# C programming malloc and NULL

Tags: c, malloc

I am very new to C programming and am working on a project for school that involves a binary search tree. In the instructions, it states that we must call malloc for each node in the tree.

When I declare the head node, is there a difference between the following statements? If so, which is the proper way? I feel like the first is the correct way:

```
    struct Node* head = NULL; 
    head = (struct Node*) malloc(1 * sizeof(struct Node));
```

and

```
    struct Node* head = (struct Node*) malloc(1 * sizeof(struct Node));
    head = NULL;
```

Comment: [Do I cast the result of malloc? **No.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @drumGod31: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 2):

Version B is a more concise version of Version A, if you remove the second line (with `= NULL`) because that undoes all the work you did on the first line.

Let's break it down, and start with `(struct Node*) malloc(1 * sizeof(struct Node))`. The `malloc` call allocates a certain amount of memory, which is 1 times the size of a `struct Node`. The beginning part of that just says "treat this as a pointer to a `struct Node`"; without this, it's just treated as a "pointer to... something" (aka a `void *`).

You don't actually *need* that `(struct Node *)` at the beginning, since the variable you're assigning it to is a `struct Node *` variable, but some people prefer it. I personally don't write it, because it stops the computer warning me about a certain type of error caused by a typo that I make frequently.

Now to the differences between the versions. Version A:

1. Sets the pointer to `NULL`.
2. Allocates some memory.
3. Sets the pointer to point to that memory.

Version B:

1. Allocates some memory.
2. Sets the pointer to point to that memory.
3. Sets the pointer to `NULL`...

You can see why this would be a problem.

- You have a pointer to `NULL` instead of to somewhere you can store data; and
- You have claimed some memory for your program but have no way of `free`ing it; your program has leaked memory.

This is bad. I recommend using version B, but only the first line from it; never ever ever set a `malloc`'d pointer to `NULL` without `free`ing it first or your program will slowly break.

Answer (score 2):

"If so, which is the proper way?" implies at least 1 of the 2 is of them is a good choice.

Use these axioms

1. Prefer [dry vs. wet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code.  Drop the cast.  No need to re-assign a variable that has not been used.
2. [Resource acquisition is initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).  Initialize a variable when possible.
3. Check allocation success.  Did the `*alloc()` call succeed?
4. Allocate to the size of the referenced object, not the type.  Easier to code right, review and maintain.

---

Let us consider a 3rd alternative as the 2 OP code snippets do not well follow all of those axioms.

```
struct Node* head = malloc(sizeof *head); 

// Check for allocation failure
if (head == NULL) {
  // Handle out of memory in some fashion
  fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

Comment: @chqrlie: Or `return EXIT_FAILURE;` if this is the `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is correct. The second one leads to memory leaks and (possibly; if you continue to use `head`) to segfaults.

In case of the second one, you assign a pointer to a piece of code returned from `malloc` to `head`. And right afterwards, you overwrite that value with `NULL`, causing the `head` variable to be basically useless. At the same time, you lose the pointer to the `malloc`d memory. You can never use or reclaim that memory, which is called a "memory leak".

Comment: why does the second lead to memory leaks?

Comment: You overwrite the value, losing it. And then you can never `free()` that memory.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is "correct", but does an unnecessary assignment of head = NULL, since it's immediately followed by a second assignment of head = ... malloc(...), overwriting the NULL assignment. Note that malloc() will return NULL if it fails to allocate memory.

Answer (score 1):

In the second version, you overwrite the pointer value obtained from `malloc()` with `NULL` and therefore cannot access this memory anymore, a situation called a *memory leak*: definitely not what you want.

The first version is not incorrect, but initializing the pointer to `NULL` is redundant since you immediately store the return value of `malloc()` into it. The compiler will probably omit this redundant store, but for readability, you can simplify it as:

```
struct Node *head = (struct Node*)malloc(1 * sizeof(struct Node));
```

Note that casting the return value of `malloc` is useless in C and somewhat error prone. It is recommended to just write:

```
struct Node *head = malloc(1 * sizeof(struct Node));
```

As a matter of fact, the `1 *` is usually omitted:

```
struct Node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
```

Note that it is also error prone to use an explicit type in the `malloc` argument as the C compiler will not perform any kind of consistency check between the size allocated and the pointer type. If you later change the type of `head` or use a different type by mistake, the size may be incorrect. For a safer way to specify the size to allocate, use the target type of the destination pointer:

```
struct Node *head = malloc(sizeof(*head));
```

For an even safer alternative, use `calloc()` that will initialize the memory to all bits 0, which on most current hardware is the zero value for integer and floating point members and the null pointer value for all pointer types. One more advantage is you can specify the number of items to allocate, as you seem to like:

```
struct Node *head = calloc(1, sizeof(*head));  // all members initialized to zero
```

In all cases, testing if the memory allocation succeeded is highly recommended:

```
struct Node *head = calloc(1, sizeof(*head));  // all members initialized to zero
if (head == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "memory allocation failed\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

You could further simplify the expression with `sizeof *head` instead of `sizeof(*head)`. These are equivalent, the parentheses are redundant. I personally omit them only for a naked identifier, as in `sizeof head`, but use them for any other expression. Conversely, parentheses are required for a type, as in `sizeof(struct Node)`

Answer (score 0):

All statements in 'c' are executed sequntially (except from jumps, like `for` or `while` loops).

So, int the first fragment you declared the variable 'head' and assigned it a value of NULL, secondly, you allocated memory and assigned its address to the `head`, overriding the previous value of `NULL`.  Now you can use the 'head' variable to point to the allocated memory in the program.

In the second fragment you did an opposit. You allocated memory first and assigned its address to `head`, then you overwrote this value with NULL. Now you cannot point to the allocated memory since you have lost the pointer. Your program will not work and your memory leaked, since it cannot be freed later (becais it has no pointer info to it).

Answer (score 0):

You can even just write `struct Node* head = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node))` without the NULL initialisation since you declare and then directly allocate memory. Use `bzero(head, sizeof(struct Node));` (include strings.h) if you actually want to zero-fill what you previously allocated.

The second method is just wrong because now head points to NULL and there's no more reference to the previously allocated memory, resulting in memory leaks.